# feature cross paste column by column

Tags: r, paste

An data.frame D1 with 3 rows and 3 colmuns like below:

```
C1 C2 C3
a  x  1 
b  y  2
c  z  3
```

I want D1 to paste its' columns by each other, just like:

```
a_x a_1 x_1
b_y b_2 y_2
c_z c_z z_3
```

How could I get this new dataframe efficiently.

Comment: My code is cross <- NULL
for (i in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){
      remain <- (i+1):ncol(data)
      dele <- matrix(paste(data[,i], data[, remain], sep="_"), nrow=nrow(data), byrow=F)
      cross <- cbind(cross, dele)    
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn`

```
D1[] <- combn(D1, 2, FUN = function(x) paste(x[,1], x[,2], sep="_"))
D1
#   C1  C2  C3
#1 a_x a_1 x_1
#2 b_y b_2 y_2
#3 c_z c_3 z_3
```

#### data

```
D1 <- structure(list(C1 = c("a", "b", "c"), C2 = c("x", "y", "z"), 
C3 = 1:3), .Names = c("C1", "C2", "C3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```